# Making a particle smoke simulation into an action

Tags: particles, keyframes, actions

Question. I’m working on rigging an internal combustion engine and need to create a burning gas.
I can do it once with a partial simulator and a smoke domain, but only once. In a perfect world I would like to apply the Same simulation several times so it can be used on different cylinders.
Similar to creating an action that can then be used with the action constraint.
Problem is there is no key frame option on starting and stopping the emitter, so can’t make it an action.

Any help is appreciated even if it’s a different direction.
Thanks